# How to enable code coverage output in job list for PHP project on gitlab.com

Tags: php, phpunit, gitlab, code-coverage, gitlab-ci

For a project hosted at https://www.gitlab.com I would like to setup code coverage in the CI setup, so it can be displayed in the job list

[image: job list in gitlab.com project]

My configuration looks like this:

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: php:7.1.1

cache:
  paths:
  - vendor/

before_script:
# Install git, the php image doesn't have installed
- apt-get update -yqq
- apt-get install git -yqq

# Install composer
- curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

# Install all project dependencies
- php composer.phar install

# Run our tests
test:
    only:
        - master
        - develop
    script:
        - vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml --coverage-text --colors=never
```

The job succeeds, but shows the error message

**Error:         No code coverage driver is available**

[image: no code coverage found job output]

I have updated the [setting for Test coverage parsing](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/pipelines/settings#test-coverage-parsing) and set the regex to

```
^\s*Lines:\s*\d+.\d+\%
```

the example for PHP/PHPUnit.

When I run the command

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never
```

locally, I get the following output:

```
Code Coverage Report:     
  2017-06-21 14:52:55     

 Summary:                 
  Classes: 100.00% (4/4)  
  Methods: 100.00% (14/14)
  Lines:   100.00% (43/43)

\Rodacker\CartExample::Article
  Methods: 100.00% ( 6/ 6)   Lines: 100.00% ( 11/ 11)
\Rodacker\CartExample::ArticleLoader
  Methods: 100.00% ( 2/ 2)   Lines: 100.00% ( 21/ 21)
\Rodacker\CartExample::ArticleRepository
  Methods: 100.00% ( 3/ 3)   Lines: 100.00% (  6/  6)
\Rodacker\CartExample::Image
  Methods: 100.00% ( 3/ 3)   Lines: 100.00% (  5/  5)
```

Comment: you are missing xdebug on your runner.

Comment: yes, that is what I figured out as well. Had problem installing it via `apt-get` but it works using pecl.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem was the missing Xdebug installation in the docker image. I could not install a proper version using `apt-get`, so I had to add a `pecl install xdebug` call in the `before_script` section:

```
image: php:7.1.1

cache:
  paths:
  - vendor/

before_script:
# Install git, the php image doesn't have installed
- apt-get update -yqq
- apt-get install git -yqq

# Install Xdebug
- pecl install xdebug
- docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Install composer
- curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

# Install all project dependencies
- php composer.phar install

# Run our tests
test:
    only:
        - master
    script:
        - vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml --coverage-text --colors=never
```

Comment: Yes it does the job BUT how about the coverage report. How the Gitlab ci/cd exposes the coverage report once the test done?

Comment: @RiteshAryal - In the project's -- Settings > CI / CD > General pipelines > Test coverage parsing ... there are examples.  I think that's what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

For people who are searching why PHPUnit is not outputting coverage report when run in CI there are some changes required.

In my case it was with PHP 7.3 CLI version and phpunit 9.4.3 coverage report was missing when run `vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml.dist --coverage-text --colors=never`, in log file it was outputted `Warning: xdebug.mode=coverage has to be set in php.ini`.

Solved it by adding xdebug.ini file with xdebug attribute `xdebug.mode=coverage` to PHP conf.d folder. To find where is your php.ini file is located run `php -i |grep php\.ini`

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my case I had to add a pair of parentheses (capturing group) in my coverage regex. This is an extract from my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
phpunit:
  image: php:8.0
  stage: qa
  before_script:
    - pecl install xdebug
    - docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
  script: XDEBUG_MODE=coverage vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text
  coverage: /\s+Lines:\s+(\d+\.\d+%)/
```

Also I recommend to move all PHPUnit configuration to `phpunit.xml`.

Comment: Please, thank you. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @sk001 glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I use Docker containers and Gitlab CI.

I have a typical PHPUnit config.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/9.3/phpunit.xsd" bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php" colors="true">
  <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
    <include>
      <directory>src</directory>
    </include>
    <report>
      <clover outputFile="phpunit.coverage.xml"/>
    </report>
  </coverage>
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="My Suite">
      <directory>tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

A part of configuration for testing. `vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never` and `coverage: '/^\s*Lines:\s*\d+.\d+\%/'` are required for the test coverage.

```yaml
testing:
  image: $CI_REGISTRY/my-images/ci-docker-compose:latest
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --build
    - docker-compose exec -T my-php-container vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never
  coverage: '/^\s*Lines:\s*\d+.\d+\%/'
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

My Dockerfile (a part).

```
# some commands

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps autoconf file g++ gcc libc-dev pkgconf make \
    && pecl install pcov && docker-php-ext-enable pcov \
    && apk del .build-deps

# some commands
```

Here is important the following commands: `pecl install pcov && docker-php-ext-enable pcov`. They install packages for fast test coverage.

In another way you can use `xdebug` and `"xdebug.mode=coverage"` or set `DEBUG_MODE=coverage` in the Docker container before your tests.